# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] for POST method in python

Tags: python, api, flask, amazon-s3

I am trying to create a Flask POST method to upload file to my s3 Bucket in python:

Here is the code what i am trying to do:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for,render_template, request, jsonify
import flask
import boto3
from flask_cors import CORS
import os
import pandas as pd

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'path_folder'
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

app.config["DEBUG"] = False
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
CORS(app)

@app.route('/postsqlData/subsytem_upload/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    df = pd.DataFrame(os.listdir(UPLOAD_FOLDER),columns=['Paths'])
    bucket_name = "name"
    for i in range(len(df)):
       filename1 = str(df['Paths'].iloc[i])
       print(filename1)
       fileSize = os.path.getsize(filename1)
       print(fileSize)
       s3.upload_file(filename1, bucket_name,'test/{}'.format(filename1))

       print("Added")
     return "completeed"
app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

This throws the following error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line
>   2446, in wsgi_app                                 response =
>   self.full_dispatch_request()
>   File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line
>   1951, in full_dispatch_request                    rv =
>   self.handle_user_exception(e)
>   File
>   "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py",
>   line 161, in wrapped_function               return
>   cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
>   File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line
>   1820, in handle_user_exception                    reraise(exc_type,
>   exc_value, tb)
>   File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py",
>   line 39, in reraise                                raise value
>   File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line
>   1949, in full_dispatch_request                    rv =
>   self.dispatch_request()
>   File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line
>   1935, in dispatch_request                         return
>   self.view_functionsrule.endpoint
>   File "s3_test.py", line 30, in upload_file
>   fileSize = os.path.getsize(filename1)
>   File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\genericpath.py", line 50, in
>   getsize                                                return
>   os.stat(filename).st_size
>   FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file
>   specified: 'data.xlsx'

If i run this code individually i.e line by line. The script runs successfully and uploads the files to s3 bucket . 
But,
It does not run this when i use post method
How can i solve this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: script may run in different folder then you expect and it may not find file. Check `print( os.getcwd() )` to see `Current Working Directory`

Comment: @furas, I could print all the files in the given path folder. i.e `print(df)` in the above example.It correctly lists all the files.

Comment: @furas, You are right i just moved files to that particular folder where my code is . I could run it successfully

Comment: `print(df)` shows values in dataframe but it doesn't check if you are in correct folder and if these names exist in this folder.

Comment: you may have to use `UPLOAD_FOLDER + filename1` to get access to file - or better `os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, filename1)`

Comment: BTW: you don't need dataframe for this - `for filename1 in os.listdir(UPLOAD_FOLDER)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.listdir(UPLOAD_FOLDER)` gives you only filenames but you need

```
os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, filename1)
```

to access file in folder `UPLOAD_FOLDER`

```
fileSize = os.path.getsize( os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, filename1) )
```

---

**BTW:** you don't need `dataframe` to get filenames but you may need `full_path` in `upload_file()`

```
   for filename1 in os.listdir(UPLOAD_FOLDER):
       print(filename1)

       full_path = os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, filename1)
       print(full_path)

       fileSize = os.path.getsize( full_path )
       print(fileSize)

       s3.upload_file( full_path , bucket_name,'test/{}'.format(filename1))
```

Comment: I added one more line to it using your logic. `filename2 = os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, filename1)` and changed name of filename in s3 upload, `s3.upload_file(filename2, bucket_name,'test/{}'.format(filename1))`